# Create new users and put them in a group with low privilege

Tags: raspbian, user

I try to create new users and put them in a group with low privilege. I want them to only have access to their home (not to other folders).
I tried `useradd` but the new user has access to all folders.
I would like to have something like a user with privilege (teacher) and users with low privilege (students).
I didn't find the proper commands for that.

Comment: 1. You should NOT use `useradd` - which is a low level command, but `adduser` - this will create a user with installation defaults (not actually sure what these are on a Pi, but certainly restricted).  2. This is not Pi specific, but a standard Linux question. 3. Unless you say what you actually did we can't help.

Comment: Actually, I did `adduser`. But the users created are able to see the `pi` user and other users. And I don't want them to be able to do that.

Comment: DO NOT put detail in Comments; edit your question!

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve? Make sure a user cannot get names of other users?

Comment: I don't want users to see other users folders or files.

Comment: This is a general question about Unix permissions and has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi. I think you mean that a user should not have any access (list directory, read, write, execute) to the home directory of other users. But he must have at least read access to system files. You should have a look at the **umask** for default permission setting and also **libpam** comes to play with this (for setting umask on login). You should ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with the new user:-

`/home/pi` has `drwxr-xr-x`  permissions, which grants read access to Everyone

You need to study Linux permissions.